# If $z=1+2i$ is a root of the equation $z^2+az+ b$ find the values of $a$ and $b$

Tags: complex-numbers

[pic of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ocjg.png)

I have no idea how to answer this, but I'm sure it's pretty simple.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): edit your post to include your work.

Comment: The question (in your picture)  is very bad formulated: $z^2+az+b$ is not an equation, and the respective domains for $z$ ($\Bbb C$?) and mainly for $a,b$ ($\Bbb R$?) are not mentionned.

Comment: If $a,b \in R$ then you can substitute $z^2+az+b = 0 $ with $z = 1+2i$ and equate the real and imaginary parts of both the sides.

Comment: wiki or google quadratic equation.

Comment: @mick No, solving $(1+2i)^2+a(1+2i)+b=0$ requires no knowledge of quadratic equations.

Comment: @AnneBauval a polyomial of degree 2 is only completely determined by both zero's.

Comment: @AnneBauval I mean more vieta than discriminant ...

Comment: @mick No need to know that the other zero is $1-2i$ to [determine the unique $(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2$ s.t. $(1+2i)^2+a(1+2i)+b=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4805500/timeline#comment_10221500).

Comment: @AnneBauval now you assume real $a,b$. The OP did not.

Comment: I don't see that $a,b$  are demanded real.

Comment: Though certainly wanted, it was indeed missing in the picture and that was part of my 2nd comment above. Anyway, even looking for the set of complex solutions $(a,b)$ requires no knowledge about quadratic equations. @mick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $z = 1 + 2i$ is a root of the expression $z^2 + az + b$, we have that

$(1+2i)^2 + (1+2i)a + b = 0 \\
1 + 4i - 4 + a + 2ai + b = 0 \\
(-3 + a + b) + (4 + 2a)i = 0$

From the equality above we obtain the following system:

$\begin{cases}
a+ b = 3 \\
2a = - 4
\end{cases}$

From this it's not hard to see that $a = -2$ and $b = 5$.

Comment: This question goesin many ways against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it. They didn't even acknowledge the constraint $a,b\in\Bbb R$